# Grammar Game (Python) not working, how do I fix it?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on a grammar game (Python), but it is not working. How do I fix it?
Code:

```
print("Welcome! Type in 'Enter' (without apostrophes) to begin")
start = input
if start == "Enter":
 print "Fill in the blanks: I __ a boy"
answer = input
if answer != "am":
 print "Wrong answer! Try again: I __ a boy"
if answer == "am":
print "Congratulations!"
```

It returns this:

`Welcome! Type in 'Enter' (without apostrophes) to begin
Wrong answer! Try again: I __ a boy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't actually getting any input from the user, when you write `start = input` you are setting the variable start equal to the builtin function input. To actually get input you need to use `start = input(prompt)` like shown [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input).

```
start = input("Welcome! Type in 'Enter' (without apostrophes) to begin")
if start == "Enter":
    answer = input("Fill in the blanks: I __ a boy")
    if answer != "am":
        print "Wrong answer! Try again: I __ a boy"
    elif answer == "am":
        print "Congratulations!"
```